# Sending multipart/form-data from Angular Frontend to .NetCore Backend

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, multipartform-data

I am trying to send info from my Frontend (Angular) to my RestApi made in .NetCore but I am getting a 400:Bad Request response all the time. Below I will leave the code from my component ts and html file and the code of my controller and service in the backend.

### HTML

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="create">
  <h2>Create Achievement</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Description</p>
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="achievementInfo.Description"
      placeholder="Description"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
    <br />
    <p>Value</p>
    <input
      type="number"
      [(ngModel)]="achievementInfo.Value"
      placeholder="Value"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
    <br />
    <p>Type</p>
    <select
      class="form-select form-select-sm"
      aria-label=".form-select-sm example"
      [(ngModel)]="achievementInfo.Type"
    >
      <option value="Score">Score</option>
      <option value="Kills">Kills</option>
      <option value="Rounds">Rounds</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Medal</p>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="achievementInfo.MedalFile"
        class="form-control"
        type="file"
        id="formFile"
      />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addAchievement()">Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### ts File

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Achievement } from '../models/Achievement';
import { RestService } from '../rest.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-achievement-add',
  templateUrl: './achievement-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./achievement-add.component.css']
})
export class AchievementAddComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() achievementInfo:Achievement=new Achievement();

  constructor(public rest: RestService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addAchievement(){
    this.rest.createAchievement(this.achievementInfo).subscribe(
      (result:any) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.router.navigate(['/achievements']);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      
      }
    );
  }
}
```

### Rest Api call

```
const httpOptionsForm={
  headers:new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
  }),
};

 createAchievement(ach:Achievement):Observable<Achievement>{
  const form= new FormData;
    form.append("Description",ach.Description);
    form.append("Type",ach.Type);
    form.append("Value",ach.Value);
    form.append("MedalFile",ach.MedalFile);
    return this.http.post<Achievement>(
      endpoint + 'Achievement/Create',
      form
    );
  }
```

### Backend Controller

```
 public class AchievementController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IAchievementService _achievementService;
        private IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        private IMapper _mapper ;

        public AchievementController(IAchievementService achievementService, IMapper mapper, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            _achievementService = achievementService;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _webHostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Achievement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">Model Create Achievement</param>
        [Authorize(Roles = Entity.Type.Admin)]
        [HttpPost("Create")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]AchievCreateModel model)
        {
            model.Medal = await SaveImage(model.MedalFile);
            var achievement = _mapper.Map<Achievement>(model);

            try
            {
                _achievementService.Create(achievement);
                return Ok(new {Message = "Achievement Created!!" });
            }
            catch (AppException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
}
```

### Backend Service

```
 public class AchievementService : IAchievementService
    {
        private DataContext _context;

        public AchievementService(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method create a new Achievement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="achievement"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Achievement Create(Achievement achievement)
        {
            if (_context.Achievement.Any(x => x.Description == achievement.Description))
                throw new AppException("Description already used in another Achievement!!");
            _context.Achievement.Add(achievement);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return achievement;
        }
```

Comment: I think you’ll need formData for this..

Comment: I do have it in my httpOptionsForm

Comment: You don’t need that header, you need to add your data using formData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData. Also, your http post call is incorrect, should be url, payload, options

Comment: I´ve tried to use FormData but I am getting this error when I try to append Value
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'(edited my question with that piece of code)

Comment: In this scenario, there are two possibilities which could make this error. The post can not send the data properly. Another scenario is the exception in `AchievementService.Create`.

Comment: @FábioPires, through your code, we can not reproduce the problem. So you can share some necessary detail error message include client and server.